# Where can I find another Stinker: Malbodoom lure?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

So, in all my hubris, I thought that my measly upgraded rod would stand a chance against the [Vesper Gar](http://ff15wiki.com/wiki/Vesper_Gar) that I needed to catch for the Navyth's Challenge: Vesper Gar quest. Needless to say, **it did not**.

Unfortunately, as I mentioned above, I failed to catch the Vesper Gar, as it broke my line, so I lost my one and only Stinker: Malbodoom lure that specifically attracts Vesper Gars. Even more unfortunately, despite having picked the first one up next to Navyth, there was not another on the ground after I lost this one.

I've tried to visit every fishing store I have come across while playing the game and buy at least 2 of every lure in case of situations like this, but I've never seen a Stinker: Malbodoom lure in any of them. Is there a way to get another or was the one I lost the only one in the game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated on [Stinker: Malbodoom](http://ff15wiki.com/wiki/Stinker:_Malbodoom), you can purchase the lure at the *Bert's Bobbers ’n' Stuff* fishing shop. This shop is located by the Vesterpool's parking spot and you can find your way to the shop by following this video

Comment: I believe there is one other location as well, but this one works best for the Gar anyway as its just down the road.